# Image auto resize if image size is too large after upload

Tags: php, html, image, file-upload, user-input

I have searched around the internet, and have been working on the following code:

It will allow the user to upload the image. At this time, it has certain restrictions like if file size is too big it will not be uploaded. I want to remove that and instead it would scale it down proportionally (to retain quality) until lets say it falls under 80000KB if the image uploaded is too large or scale it down to relative number of around 350 width x 125 height. My other issue is that when the file is uploaded it indicates where it is stored, for instance, "upload/picture.jpg". I would prefer it the complete url was provided instead, so that when someone clicks on it, it takes them directly to the image file page.

Here is what I have so far
On the page where user uploads an image

```
<h3>Upload Event Image</h3>
         <form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <label for="file">Filename:</label>
         <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
         </form>
```

The upload function itself found at a different page

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
} else {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
}
?>

<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  } else {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  }
} else {
  echo "Invalid file";
}
?>

<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 100000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  } else {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    } else {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }
  }
} else {
  echo "Invalid file";
}
?>
```

Any help or suggestion would be deeply appreciated

Comment: make filename extension strtolower so you can check it in array. sometime people have uppercase file extension.

Comment: @djay i dont understand why people still call them w3fools . as the code is taken from w3schools.

Comment: @AMB no one is claiming anything, especially in CS where new codes are generated from a collection of previous codes. In fact, nearly every app recognizes many open source, or other source they may used for the creation of the application, and I intend to do the same. I personally had to use my dell laptop to input the code, so if i didn't have access to a computer or a smartphone, this would probably not be possible. What people are claiming is the result, where each different components of the creation may have been derived from external sources. At least read my first line in my post.

Comment: @user3827788 my point was , the code is so perfect still people call them w3fools. idk what you assumed .

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your point, and was under the impression that I was being accused of claiming that the complete code was my creation, when I never claimed so, and in the actual application, I would credit accordingly. This code is great, but far from being perfect as perfection does not exist and requires continuous and ongoing effort to boost efficiency and productivity, which I why I am here.  My intent is so that if the image uploaded is too large, it would scale proportionally automatically until the minimum file size specified has been reached.

Comment: @user3827788 i undertand thats why i left comment of using strtolower to check the extension. and $_FILES["file"]["type"] isnt foolproof.